# how to handle xpath in cypress where text contains a single quote in Cypress

Tags: javascript, xpath, cypress

Xpaths I tried as below :

```
cy.xpath("`//*[contains(text(),'Didn't receive an email?')]`");
cy.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'`Didn't receive an email?')`]");
cy.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Didn't receive an email?')]");
```

Getting same Error as below[image]

Comment: Does `cy.xpath(\`//*[contains(text(),"Didn't receive an email?")]\`);` work?

Comment: @MartinHonnen no, getting error as "Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(text(),'Didn't receive an email?')]' is not a valid XPath expression."

Comment: Well, my example doesn't have `'Didn't receive an email?'`, it has `"Didn't receive an email?"`, so either you did not copy it as posted or your API rewrites strings.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen. I miss type your first comment. It is working as per your first comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 1.0 has two different string delimiters `'` and `"`, JavaScript now has three with e.g. `'`, `"` and the backtick so I would use the backtick as the outer JavaScript string delimiter to allow you to use the double quote in XPath as the string delimiter for the string containing an apostroph:

```
cy.xpath(`//*[contains(text(),"Didn't receive an email?")]`);
```